# Fitting data to a sum of correlated polynomials. Can I de-correlate the polynomials?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, pca, polynomial

I have a model that has the form
$$f(x; a, b) = (x^2 -M)\cdot a \; +\; (x^4 + M\cdot x^2 + M^2)\cdot b$$
where $M$ for all intents and purposes is known. The domain of the problem is for $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$ although I only have data for finite $x$. 
I know polynomials form an infinite dimensional vector-space in $\mathbb{R}$ which gave me an idea. Let me rewrite my model as 
$$f(x; a, b) = p_2(x)\cdot a + p_4(x)\cdot b $$ where $(p_2, p_4) \neq 0$ where $(*,*)$ denotes the inner product between the two. Choosing $p_2(x)$ as one of my basis vectors, I can, in principle, construct a new $\tilde{p_4}$. Then for $\tilde{p_2} = p_2$ I have can construct a linear mapping between my old model and new model
$$\tilde{f}(x;a, b) = 
\begin{pmatrix}a\cdot\tilde{p_2}\\ \phi(a,b)\cdot\tilde{p4}\end{pmatrix}
= M \begin{pmatrix} a\cdot p_2 \\ b\cdot p_4 \end{pmatrix}
$$ for some $\phi(a, b)$.

The point is, if I know $M$, then I can project my data to the space that is only effected by $\tilde{p_2}(x)$. In other words, I can fit 
$$(x^2 - M)\cdot a \rightarrow Proj_{\tilde{p_2}}(x)$$ 
Then once I know $a$ I can fit to my other parameter $b$
$$ \phi(a, b)\tilde{p_4} \rightarrow Proj_{\tilde{p_4}}(x)$$.

Is something like this even possible though? I *can't* just do Gram-Schmidt because the domain goes all the way to $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Your post reminded me of Hermite polynomials (after thinking about Chebyshev polynomials).

Comment: I don't understand your reference to "$\infty,$" because your space is only two-dimensional and this is a routine regression problem.  This might become clear simply by changing notation: writing $x_1=x^2-M$ and $x_2=x^4+Mx^2+M^2$ makes the model $f(x_1,x_2;a,b) = ax_1+bx_2.$

Comment: My model is just a truncated Taylor series. So in principle I have an infinite-degree polynomial. In any case it should not matter since given one vector another orthogonal vector can be construct.

I was hoping to apply some transformation matrix to my data that would simplify my regression problem into two more simple regression problems. But upon further though I think something like this is impossible. A projection operator that separates out polynomials cannot project out actual data itself. Constructing such an operator would be equivalent to just solving the problem.